# Classic ASP Generate xls or csv with readonly fields

Tags: asp-classic

At the top of my page I have the code

```
<% 
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.xls"%>
```

which forces my table to download as a spreadsheet. But, how can I make certain cells of this download read only ?

Comment: Are you actually creating an xls formatted file or a csv one?  If it is a csv one there is no way can can make cells readonly as that is not a feature of csv.

Comment: You could send the data as SpreadsheetML format (not to be confused with Office Open XML). Check out http://m8y.org/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_Reference_Schemas/Help/html/spreadsheetml_HV01151864.htm for details. Look at protected worksheets and locked cells